# Best way to accumulate results in a vector in Clojure? (Pure functional code seems ugly and verbose)

Tags: recursion, clojure, functional-programming, lisp

...Maybe imperative programming with mutable data is just drilled too deep into my brain, but I find the code for building up vectors of data in Clojure to be verbose, unwieldy, and convoluted. There must be a better way!

In Ruby I might write code like:

```
results = []
a_collection.each do |x|
  x.nested_collection.each do |y|
    next if some_condition_holds
    results << y
  end
end
```

In Clojure, I don't know of a better way to do that than to use a recursive function, perhaps like the following (horrendous) code:

```
; NEWBIE ALERT! NEWBIE ALERT!
(loop [results   []
       remaining a_collection]
  (if (empty? remaining)
      results
      (recur
        (loop [results results
               nested  (nested_collection (first remaining))]
           (if (empty? nested)
               results
               (if (some_condition_holds)
                   (recur results (rest nested))
                   (recur (conj results (first nested)) (rest nested))))) 
        (rest remaining))))
```

Without mutable data and iterative loops, you need to use recursion to build up a collection. Each such recursive function needs an `(empty?)` guard clause, etc. etc. The whole thing is so repetitive it makes me want to scream.

In simple cases, `map` would be enough, but I'm thinking of cases where there are multiple levels of nesting, and at each level, there may be conditions which require skipping an iteration.

In Common Lisp I might use the `loop` macro, or `mapcan`. Doesn't Clojure have anything like `mapcan`?

Comment: It has been said before, but the basis of functional programming is composing functions and using higher order functions, not the use of recursion. As a rule, recursion should only be used if a solution with HOFs would get more complex than one using recursion.

Comment: To elaborate: you'll use tons of recursion, but almost all of it should be recursion that someone else already wrote for you, eg in `map` - it should be fairly rare to write recursion by hand.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In descending order of how nice I think the options look:

```
(for [x coll,
      y (nested-collection x)
      :when (not (some-condition-holds y))]
  y)
```

Alternatively, if you'd rather build it out of functions like `map` and `mapcat` instead of using the `for` syntax:

```
(mapcat (fn [x]
          (remove some-condition-holds
                  (nested-collection x)))
        coll)
```

If you are really keen on it, you can also build it with partial function applications and composition:

```
(mapcat (comp (partial remove some-condition-holds)
              nested-collection)
        coll)
```

This third style doesn't read very well in Clojure, although equivalent code in some other languages is very nice. In Haskell, for example:

```
coll >>= (filter (not . someConditionHolds) . nestedCollection)
```

Answer (score 7):

```
(mapcat (fn [y] (filter condition y)) x)
```

Answer (score 7):

Others have already provided answers regarding how to solve the specified problem using FP concepts like using high order functions. If you analyse your thought process which lead to your existing code and compare that with FP solutions that other people have provided, you will find that whenever you think of - "having a variable to store the processed result" - it will lead to imperative OR step-by-step kind of solution and hence your Clojure code is mostly imperative as you thought about storing the result is a "vector variable". This kind of thinking won't allow you to apply FP concepts which are based on "evaluation of expression" and "solving problem by composition"

Comment: to play devil's advocate, and out of naivety, how does functional composition differ from "step by step", apart from that each function's arguments are immutable vars ?

Comment: Eventually it all execute as "step by step" but the difference is how you think about the solution. Ex: multiply is a result of composition of add and similarly everything in this world is built out of composing primitive things and the glue to compose 2 things is also another primitive or compound thing.

Answer (score 4):

higher order functions can really help make it much more beautiful though
it does take a while to get used to thinking in sequences and 
transformation of sequences.

there are many ways to write this:

```
user> (into [] a_colletion)
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]

user> (vec a_colletion)
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]

user> (for [x a_colletion :when (even? x)] x) 
(0 2 4 6 8)
```

a more complex example could look something like this:

```
(flatten (for [x (map extract-from-nested-collection a_collection)
                 :when (test-conditions? x)]
            x))
```

make a nested collection

```
user> (def a_collection (map #(reductions + (range %)) (range 1 5)))
#'user/a_collection 
user> a_collection
((0) (0 1) (0 1 3) (0 1 3 6))
```

retrieve a nested collection from each element of a_collection
and skip some of them:

```
user> (map #(filter pos? %) a_collection)
(() (1) (1 3) (1 3 6))
```

append the nested collections together

```
user> (flatten (map #(filter pos? %) a_collection))
(1 1 3 1 3 6)
```

filter some anything larger than 3 from the flattened collection and then square each of them

```
user> (for [x (flatten (map #(filter pos? %) a_collection))
              :when (<= x 3)]
           (* x x))
(1 1 9 1 9)
user>
```

Comment: `into` would be good if I just wanted to append `a_collection` onto a vector; but in the example, I need to retrieve a nested collection from each element of `a_collection`, and append the nested collections together. Also, I need to filter the elements which are accumulated in the vector.

Comment: you can separate each of these into it's own action. I'll add an example soon

Comment: Thanks for the examples... I like them. But I think `(mapcat ...)` as demonstrated by @Hendekagon is better than `(flatten (map ...))`.

Answer (score 2):

[amalloy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11302808/214010) is probably best if you want to follow an idiomatic functional style and produce a lazy sequence.

If you are actually interested in imperatively constructing a vector (rather than a lazy sequence), I would probably do it using an atom and doseq as follows:

```
(let [v (atom [])]
  (doseq [x (range 5)
          y (range 5)]
    (if (> y x)
      (swap! v conj (str x y))))
  @v)

=> ["01" "02" "03" "04" "12" "13" "14" "23" "24" "34"]
```

As you can see, this ends up very similar in structure to the Ruby code.

It's also possible to do this using reduce, however this is most suitable when there is only one input sequence, e.g.:

```
(reduce
  (fn [v x] 
    (if (even? x)
      (conj v x)
      v))
  []
  (range 20))

=> [0 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18]
```

Comment: I think using `reduce` with an empty vector as the accumulator would make more sense.

Comment: @ponzao - I just added a reduce example as it happens :-) but reduce isn't well so well suited for iterating over two collections simultaneously because it forces you to construct an intermediate sequence of [x y] pairs. You might as well use amalloy's solution at that point.

Comment: Yeah okay, my bad, I didn't properly read the original question :)